# How can i store and fetch.php page in mysql

Tags: php

I have a project in which i have to make a code in which when we click on menu bar and the option that we select in menu bar the page related to that option will display all this is to be done through my sql.Is there any way to do this task.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please be more precise in what you want and what you have already done. Show code.

Comment: i just created a table in database with three fields id,title,content

Comment: i just want to save a php page in content field

Comment: You want to save PHP-code in the data base? Don't do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want and if there is a better way to do this, but don't put in your sql fields PHP code.
You can create a xml document instead, and use it better.[PHP.net - XMLdocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php)